# why the parameter 'scale' of tf.layers.batch_normalization is disabled when next layer is relu?

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

In the tensorflow documentation of [tf.layers.batch_normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization),it is said" **When the next layer is linear (also e.g. nn.relu), this(the parameter of 'scale' ) can be disabled since the scaling can be done by the next layer.**" ? It seems wrong because when the next layer is nn.relu, the linear coefficient is an invariant constant(1), and the value won't be sacled.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question seems to be more about algorithms and how they work than about programming. You might have more luck with that kind of question on the cross validated board

Answer (score 0):

The layer after `nn.relu` is usually linear. Doing some scaling before or after a ReLu won't change anything (if `L` is linear, `L(relu(x))=relu(L(x)) for all x`), so having one scaling after the bartch normalization and one in the next layer is redundant.

So you can skip the scaling after batch norm followed by a ReLu if you have another linear layer after the ReLu, which is usually the case.